# Create a scope to show items above an average for all items with a particular attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a requirement where I need to create a scope to show items with a unit_sold greater than the the average of unit_sold based on the company they were sold at. There is one model with products in it. Each product has the attributes of:

product_name
unit_sold
company

There are many companies.

This scope works for calculating the average on all items.

```
scope :upward_trending, -> { where( "unit_sold > ?", average(:unit_sold)) }
```

Now I am trying to create a scope that only shows items that have an average higher than the average of units_sold for that company.

```
scope :upward_trending, ->(company) {where( "unit_sold > ?", where(company: company).average(:unit_sold)) }
```

I get the error:

> wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Using Rails 4

So the further question here is, how do I pass an argument to a scope in ActiveAdmin?

Comment: Try this `scope :upward_trending, ->(company) {where( "unit_sold > ? and company=?", average(:unit_sold),company) }`

Comment: Hey @Pavan thanks so much for your comment. Unfortunately it gets the same error :(

Comment: Where are you calling the scope?  Are you supplying it with a company?

Comment: I'm calling it from an ActiveAdmin resource:

`scope :upward_trending`

How do I pass the argument in here?

Answer (score 0):

just try pass company as argument to your scope, like: `Model.upward_trending(<some_company>)`

Comment: Hey @IS04 thanks for your response. I have tried to do that as shown in the code, but I am getting an argument error. Think there is something wrong with my code, are you able to review it? Thanks

Comment: so you call your scope like `Model.upward_trending(<some_company>)`?

Comment: Thanks @IS04 I'm calling the scope from a resource in activeadmin, do I need to pass in the argument there?

Comment: yes, because I don't think that `ActiveAdmin` do it instead you

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @diosney, I gave answer, which could be correct, and we have/had some discussion about it, what is the problem?

Comment: @IS04 That comment comes from Low Quality Posts review queue. Your answer was flagged as very low quality, probably by the system itself. Obviously many reviewers think that this shouldn’t have been an answer but a mere comment below the question. While I agree partially, I don’t think it should be deleted. To me it looks like a valid answer that needs some improvement. If you come to a conclusion in the comments, you should [edit] it in. BTW what suggest that this should have been a comment is the “try” in the answer. If you are not sure, comment.